# Best list of static analysis rules

Tags: firebug, static-analysis, checkstyle, pmd

How to achieve better code in-terms of style, practical issues, logical issues, duplicate code, cyclic issues.
   Could i know your best list of static analysis rules for

```
   1. Java
   2. JSP or JSF 
   3. JavaScript, JQuery...
   4. css
```

How to achive better code 
   Please share,

Comment: For JavaScript: JSHint (scans for multiple pitfalls of JS and makes it possible to set some style requirements). But it doesn't scan for duplicate code and things like that.

Comment: There is a reason why all of these analysis tools come with so many configuration options: The settings depend on the project you are running. If there was a "best list", or if it was even possible to distill one out of many, then they'd ship it with their tools.

Answer (score 0):

For Java, try my carefully curated list and instruction for IntelliJ IDEA here: http://superliminal.com/computing/idea_static_analysis.html